# Pass in Generic Type to a method

Tags: c#, generics

Is this possible?

When a type gets passed in to a method, I want to instantiate the generic class myClass

```
public class myClass<T>
{

}

public void PassInType(Type myType)
{

myClass<myType> c=new myClass<myType>();
}
```

Update:

Okay since thats not possible, how do I do this

```
public myMethod(string myType)
{

myClass<myType> c=new myClass<myType>();

}
```

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; that's fundamentally impossible.

The whole point of generics is that they create *compile-time* types.
You're trying to create a type which is unknown at compile time.

You can do it using reflection, though.  (`typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(myType)`)