# Why does my generic <T> is not Resolved?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class Movie :

```
internal class Movie
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have this code :

```
 var Movies = CreateMovies(); //IEnumerable<Movie>
 var sorter = new Sorter<Movie>();
 sorter.AddSort(Movies,  m => m.Year , a=>a.Name ,.....as many as I want....);
```

And here is the `Sorter` class :

```
 class Sorter<T>
{
    public void AddSort(IEnumerable<T> movs,  params Expression<Func<T, object>>[]    funcs)
    {
                 /*...*/ 
        movs.OrderBy(d=>d.); //<----- here is the problem : where is the columns ?
    }
}
```

**Question :**

When I need intellisence on the `d` , it shows me :

[image]

I don't understand why `T` is not inferred as `Movie` :

Look how many locations are inferring that `T` is a `Movie` :

[image]

How can I make those Movie Fields to Appear  , **without changing to `Ienumerable<Movies>`** ?

Comment: That's not how generics work.

Comment: When you change it to `<Movie>` then the compiler knows that you're working with `Movie` items. With `<T>`, how is the compiler going to resolve that type parameter within the method?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when AddSort is called with something other than Movie?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes I forgot to add the generic constraint. ( too tired). thanks. **I vote to close it.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

at the time of compiling `Sorter` class, the compiler doesn't know what type it's going to be, so it can't tell if the user that will use it will have an `Year` property or not.

however, you can use [where constrains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx):

```
class Sorter<T> where T: Movie
```

that way the compiler knows that the given class of `T` will have `Year` property as well as other properties

> In a generic type definition, the where clause is used to specify
>   constraints on the types that can be used as arguments for a type
>   parameter defined in a generic declaration. For example, you can
>   declare a generic class, MyGenericClass, such that the type parameter
>   T implements the IComparable interface:

so as it says you don't even have to do

```
class Sorter<T> where T: Movie
```

we can just be satisfied with

```
class Sorter<T> where T: ImyInterface
```

and `ImyInterface` will contain properties of `Name` and `Year`.

Comment: but that defeats the purpose of having generics in the first place. Why `Sorter<T>` and not simply `MovieSorter`?

Comment: @w0lf: You can constrain a type parameter while still keeping it polymorphic.

Comment: @BoltClock But there should be two classes than: `Sorter<T>` and `MovieSorter : Sorter<T>`, shouldn't they?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, my point is that `Sorter<T> where T: Movie` is the equivalent of `MovieSorter`, where all occurrences of `T` are replaced with `Movie` (i.e. a non-generic class)

Answer (score 1):

I did not try this code, but I think you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
foreach(var func in funcs)
    movs = movs.OrderBy(func);
```

to simply delegate the sorting funcs to the OrderBy method, without you caring what those funcs are and what class is T (which defeats the purpose of generics).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I interpret your question and the intention:

1> you are using Sorter class vs non generic Sorter , as you are intending this class to handle multiple Types.

2> Since for AddSort method you are expecting it to be based on Movie class members, hence that indicated that you would be having derived classes based on Movie class like XYXMovie:Movie ,etc, for which Sorter would be used.

If my above observations are correct then you need to tie your Sorter class to the base class "Movie", so that it can handle all types derived from class Movie.

For doing this you must use where constrains, like class Sorter where T: Movie.

This makes your Sorter class tied to the base class Movie, but can handle all its sub-classes.