# Use of Enum.GetValues give me a compilation error

Tags: c#, enums, getvalue

I have this code to list the values of an enum:

```
Type myType1 = Type.GetType("QBFC16Lib.ENTxnType");

var enumList = Enum.GetValues(myType1)
     .Cast<myType1>()
     .Select(d => (d, (int)d))
     .ToList();
```

I receive a compilation error in .Cast(myType1). The error is:
"myType1 is variable but is used as a type"

If instead of MyType1 I use QBFC16Lib.ENTxnType in both places it works perfetly.

How can modify the code to overcome that error?

Comment: Right, you can't cast to a Type variable.  It's a compile-type-vs-run-time thing.  However, you can use `Convert.ChangeType`.  I'll close this with a duplicate link you can check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting a variable using a Type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972636/casting-a-variable-using-a-type-variable)

Comment: @TimRoberts there is no need to cast or convert here, `Enum.GetValues` result is already of "correct" type.

Comment: Have you considered using `Enum.GetValues<TEnum>()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-7.0#system-enum-getvalues-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) in C# require type name to be passed to [generic type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters), not the instance of `System.Type` (basically [generics are "resolved" at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17734497/2501279), so you can't use them dynamically via `System.Type` instance without some kind of runtime compilation or [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)). If you want to use LINQ you can "workaround" with `object` (note that underlying values are already of "correct" type - `Enum.GetValues(myType1).GetValue(0).GetType() == myType1` is true):

```cs
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(myType1)
     .OfType<object>()
     .Select(d => (d, (int)d))
     .ToList();
```

Note that this relies on that `QBFC16Lib.ENTxnType` has `int` as [underlying type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums#192-enum-declarations), i.e. the following will throw `InvalidCastException` exception:

```cs
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
    .OfType<object>()
    .Select(d => (d, (int)d))
    .ToList();

enum MyEnum : byte
{
    None,
    One,
    Two
}
```

Comment: May be you can help with another problem I got. When I tried to use that code in a library from QuickBooks SDK (QBFC16.lib) . I was receiving null in some enums and not in others in the line: Type myType1 = Type.GetType("QBFC16Lib.ENTxnType").